# my web application connect with database from one windows user account but not with second windows user account

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I create a web application in visual studio 2010 (mvc3 razor) and use my own database in sql server 2008 r2 and added aspdbnet database in my database by using regsql tool. i create users and roles in it all working is well. I use my laptop for creating application and my system name is Zulfiqar_PC.I have two different user accounts on my system

- Administrator
- Zulfiqar

I have done all my working in Zulfiqar user account while working with website administration tool. and it works fine but now when i want to run my application from second user that is administrator then it doesnot return me the data and give me error that 
**"Login failed for user 'Zulfiqar-PC\Administrator'."**

my connectionstring is same in both accounts in web.config file here is my connectionstring and other settings of database

```
<add connectionString="data source=(local);   Initial Catalog=BA; User ID=sa;Password=sql123" name="dbconnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
     <providers>
    <clear/>
    <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider,&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,&#xD;&#xA;PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="dbconnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="dbconnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="dbconnection" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

When i run the website administration tool in administaror account its user name is as under   **Current User Name:ZULFIQAR-PC\ADMINISTRATOR**

and in first account it is as under
**Current User Name:ZULFIQAR-PC\Zulfiqar**

Plz any one help me what i do to resolve this problem I already enabled sql tcp/ip ports etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating administrtor account and assign this account proper server roles in sql server. I does not had administrator account in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Try 2 Following Different Methods.

**Method 1:**

Please change database file / SQL Connection string to other like following any declarations

```
<add connectionString="data source=( CHANGE HERE TO DATABASE PATH ); Initial Catalog=BA; User ID=sa;Password=sql123" name="dbconnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

CHANGE PATH TO : DATA SOURCE PATH LIKE

`"Datasource="C:\PROJECT\MYDATABASE.mdb""        \\ Project Database`

or

use this sql serve datasource Tag

`<add name="cs" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;database=db_hrms"/>`

**Method 2:**

The Project (Web application in VS C#) that you created is present in

```
C:\Users\User_Name_1\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects
C:\Users\User_Name_2\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects
```

you must copy the project and run it with different User (other user)  **both Produces same results** for web application but it differs in windows application. **But the data base you are connecting to doesn't exists in other user.**

Comment: while changing the connectionstring it does not connect. database is exist in both accounts

Comment: <add name="cs" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;database=db_hrms"/>  here change the localhost to your PC-Name,
And Please check any spelling mistakse or password changes etc put it in . 3 Tire Architecture in web config file.

Comment: <add name="cs" connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;database=db_hrms"/>
in Web.config File and


SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();

in Click / other Event code Page.. Try.